# Need help making all fields required and printing out the answers on the right side of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make all fields required and print the result on the right side of the page but not sure what to do.

I have tried everything and can not figure it out. This is my code for the form layout when i type required into the code it does not work and nothing pops up now even though i got it to work once before.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assingment 3</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <div id="form-container" class="column">
        <h1>Sign up form</h1>
        <form id="registration" name="registration" method="GET" action="" onsubmit="">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />               
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input id="password2" name="password2" type="password"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="age">Age</label>
                <input id="age" name="age" type="number"/>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="bio" style="vertical-align: top;">Short Bio</label>
                <textarea id="bio" name="bio"></textarea>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span style="vertical-align: top;">Gender</span>
                <div id="genders">
                    <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender">Female</input>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender">Male</input>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Other" name="gender">Other</input>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="Prefer not so say" name="gender">Prefer not so say</input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label for="agreement" style="width: auto;">I agree with Terms and Conditions.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input id="submit-btn" name="submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output-container" class="column">
        <h1>Result</h1>
        <div id="output">
            <ul id="result_list">
                <li>Form not submitted yet</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}

.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label, span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}

textarea {
    height: 10em;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#genders {
    display: inline-block;
}

#output{
    color: blue;
}

#result_list{
    list-style: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(){
    var isValid = false;
    // Validate the form according to validation requirements
    var name = document.registration.name.value;
    var username = document.registration.username.value;
    var email = document.registration.email.value;
    var password = document.registration.password.value;
    var password = document.registration.password.value;
    var password2 = document.registration.password2.value;
    var age = document.registration.age.value;
    var bio = document.registration.bio.value;
    var gender = document.registration.gender.value;
    var agreement = document.registration.agreement.value;



    if(isValid){
        //Print the form input values into output div. Append each text/value as a list item of the ul#result_list using jQuery
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried ? where is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with at least half of the issue, I think.  You can make HTML inputs required by adding that as a keyword just before closing the tag.  See below.

```
        <div class="row">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required/>                
        </div>
```

I'll try helping with the JavaScript code in a bit!

Below is some example JavaScript with comments to walk you through what's going on.  I got this to work on my DOM.  Let me know if you have difficulties.

```
function validateForm(){
    console.log("hello");
    var isValid = false;

    // Validate the form according to validation requirements
    // var name = document.registration.name.value;
    // var username = document.registration.username.value;
    // var email = document.registration.email.value;
    // var password = document.registration.password.value;
    // var password = document.registration.password.value;
    // var password2 = document.registration.password2.value;
    // var age = document.registration.age.value;
    // var bio = document.registration.bio.value;
    // var gender = document.registration.gender.value;
    // var agreement = document.registration.agreement.value;

    if(isValid){
        //Print the form input values into output div. Append each text/value as a list item of the ul#result_list using jQuery
    }

    // Fetch our input data.
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    console.log(name);

    // Create a new list item to insert that data into.
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    console.log(newLi);

    // Convert out fetched data into a text node.
    let newContent = document.createTextNode(name);
    console.log(newContent);

    // Add text node to our newly created list item.
    newLi.appendChild(newContent);
    console.log(newLi);

    // // Add newly created element and its content into the DOM.
    let currentUl = document.getElementById('result_list');
    console.log(currentUl);

    currentUl.appendChild(newLi);

    return false;
}
```

Also, because you're doing all this JavaScript inside of a function called validateForm, you need to make sure to call that function in your HTML after importing the JavaScript file into you HTML via a script tag.  Notice below the onclick method.

```
            <div class="row">
                <input onclick="return validateForm()" id="submit-btn" name="submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()" value="Submit" />
            </div>
```

Comment: I actually fixed that part using javascript cause required was not working for some reason , thanks for the help

Comment: Okay!  I just updated my comment to include some code that should help print stuff to the Results unordered list with limited edits to your code.

Comment: tried it and it didnt do anything, just rest the all the fields to blank

Comment: Do you have some other code that's handling those validation requirements that we can't see?  I commented all those out because I don't know what they're doing.  Also, are you making sure to return the function call in your onclick event in the button?  It needs to return false to leave the form filled in.

Comment: all the code above is what i had, when i entered your code it did nothing

Comment: What were your all of your variables doing that were trying to access document.registration? Are you sure that when you provide the path to your scripts.js file it's the correct path? Are you sure that when you create the onclick attribute on your button you're wrapping it on quotes and returning the call?  Are you sure the scripts.js file is returning false at the end?

Comment: Also, I'd change that HTML tag for your button from an input to a button tag.